# ProtonVPN doesn't work - Ubuntu 20.05

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm running Ubuntu 20.05 and I am attempting to install ProtonVPN. I've installed the ProtonVPN app but am not able to actually run said app.
I've followed the instructions as detailed at the [following link](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/)

The output from `sudo apt-get` all looked promising.

After rebooting, nothing happens.

I searched for ProtonVPN and I can see the icon for it.
But when I click that icon, nothing happens.

When I run protonvpn from the command line, the error message is:

```
$ protonvpn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/protonvpn", line 7, in <module>
    from protonvpn_cli.cli import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'protonvpn_cli.cli' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/protonvpn_cli/cli.py)
```

```
~$ protonvpn-cli -v

ProtonVPN CLI v3.9.1 (protonvpn-nm-lib v3.4.1; proton-client v0.6.1)
```

```
~$ which python3
/home/me/miniconda3/bin/python3
```

```
~$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Comment: are you trying to run the vpn as a root nor with `sudo`  ?

Comment: To further diagnose the issue, you could try start protonvpn from the command line. Open a terminal and enter `protonvpn`. This should start the GUI application just like the icon does. Either way, you'll need to contact ProtonVPN support.

Comment: I've added the output from the command line.

Comment: What do you have for `protonvpn-cli -v` and `which python3; python3 --version`?

Comment: I've added all three.

Comment: It possibly has to do with it being run within miniconda (or the miniconda interpreter). Since I don't have enough points to comment, I'm writing this as an answer (which actually is not). I would advise to contact support at https://protonvpn.com/support-form as @david said, since they should be able to help you with this issue.

Comment: will do, thanks. And if I think its worthy, I will add the answer here once ProtonVPN support resolves the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. /usr/local/bin/protonvpn was an executable file from a previous installation. Renaming/deleting it solved the problem.

Comment: To add more detail - looking through the debs installed through the linked instructions protonvpn is installed as `/usr/bin/protonvpn` - the file at `/usr/local/bin/protonvpn` (as seen in the error message) must be from some other install - delete or move it out of the way.